# Java Encryptor/Decryptor method.

Tags: java

I'm a first year CS student looking for a better way to complete this assignment.

The instructions are as follows:

> Your application should use a dialog box to prompt the user for a four-digit number and then encrypt it as follows:  Replace each digit with the result of adding 7 to the digit and getting the remainder after dividing the new value by 10.  Then swap the first digit with the third, and swap the second digit with the fourth.  Then output the encrypted number to the console.  Your application should use loops to implement the algorithm. THEN write another application where you can enter the encrypted number and will reverse the scheme to get the original number.

We can ONLY use skills that he has taught in class (basic loops, methods, if statements) 
We have NOT learned arrays, push, stack or pop.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
public class Project5e {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //promt user for the 4 digit number
        String userIdStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your four digit user I.D.");
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(userIdStr);

        encryptId(userId);

    }//End Main Method

        public static void encryptId(int id){
        while (id > 1) {   
            int num4 = id % 10;
            id /= 10;
            int num3 = id % 10;
            id /= 10;
            int num2 = id % 10;
            id /= 10;
            int num1 = id % 10;
            id /= 10;

            num1 += 7;
            num2 += 7;
            num3 += 7;
            num4 += 7;

            num1 = num1 % 10;
            num2 = num2 % 10;
            num3 = num3 % 10;
            num4 = num4 % 10;

            int swap1, swap2, swap3, swap4;
            swap1 = num3;
            swap2 = num4;
            swap3 = num1;
            swap4 = num2;

            System.out.print(swap1);
            System.out.print(swap2);
            System.out.print(swap3);
            System.out.println(swap4);

        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 questions.

1. Should I be creating a method for each math operation? (the class today was methods)
2. How do separate digits from an integer, perform math to them, rearrange them, then put them back into a single integer?
3. What is a simpler way writing this code? (I hate how it looks and how it's performed)

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Without using arrays, I can't think of any... If you just learned about methods, you should probably use them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should do it

Check the length of the String to make sure its length of 4, use Integer.parseInt for each digit (String.subString(0),  String.subString(1) etc...
Then for each digit call your method to add 7 and divide by 10

With the four results perform your final operations

Answer (score 0):

An approach using methods could be like that;

```
public class Project5e {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // promt user for the 4 digit number
        String userIdStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your four digit user I.D.");

        new Project5e().encryptId(userIdStr);

    }// End Main Method

    private int extract(String v, int i){
        return v.charAt(i)-48; //get the digit at i position (48 is ASCII value of '0')
    }

    private int transform(int v){
        v += 7;             //transform the digit
        return v % 10;
    }

    private String swap(String r){
       return r.charAt(2) + "" + r.charAt(3)+ "" + r.charAt(0)+ "" + r.charAt(1); //swap digits
    }

    public void encryptId(String id) {
        String r = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            int v = extract(id, i);
            v = transform(v); 
            r += String.valueOf(v);
        }
        r = swap(r);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

There is one method to extract a digit, another one to transform the digit, and at last a method to swap the digit.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks eltabo. This is definitely what I need to be striving for. It's a little over my head, I'm not following all of the logic and techniques.